# Gaussian Blurring in OpenCV: set 0 constant outside the border?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using the [GaussianBlur](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=gaussianblur#gaussianblur) function in OpenCV to perform Gaussian blurring. While the **bordertype** parameter can be filled with `BORDER_CONSTANT`, it doesn't allow to set the value of the constant. From the explanation of [borderInterpolate](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=gaussianblur#int%20borderInterpolate%28int%20p,%20int%20len,%20int%20borderType%29), it seems that the value of the constant is set to -1. Is it possible to set it to 0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the -1 is the return value for the function borderInterpolate() when you use BORDER_CONSTANT. Check out the top section of this page:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=gaussianblur#image-filtering

"all the non-existing pixels are zeros (“constant border” extrapolation method)", so it does already use zeros for the GaussianBlur function.

Answer (score 1):

The reason borderInterpolate returns -1 for BORDER_CONSTANT is so this code in filter.cpp works:

```
        int srcY = borderInterpolate(dstY + dy + i + roi.y - ay,
                        wholeSize.height, columnBorderType);
        if( srcY < 0 ) // can happen only with constant border type
            brows[i] = alignPtr(&constBorderRow[0], VEC_ALIGN);
```

That is, it causes your border to be set to zero, which is what you want. The border is not being set to -1.